# Azure Powershell not creating NSG rules with multiple ports

Tags: azure, powershell

I am adding a security rule to an NSG which allows access to ports 4239,1128,1129. Via the Azure Portal, it works. Via Powershell, it refuses.

I am using following code to get the NSG, add the security rule and update the NSG.

```
$nsg = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "BITH-DEV-T1NSG" - 
ResourceGroupName "RG-BITH-HANA-POC"

$nsg | Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "SUM6" -Description "Allow 
SUM" -Access "Allow" -Protocol * -Direction "Inbound" -Priority "105" - 
SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * - 
DestinationPortRange "1128,1129,4239"

$nsg | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
```

When updating the NSG, it is giving me following error.

```
Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup : Security rule has invalid Port range. Value 
provided: 4239,1128,1129. Value should be an integer OR integer range 
with '-' delimiter.Valid range 0-65535.
```

Is it possible to add a custom range to a NSG via Powershell?

Comment: Sample : `Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName MYRG -Name MYNSG | Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name MYRULE -Access Allow -Protocol * -Direction Outbound -Priority 3001 -SourceAddressPrefix 10.200.32.36 -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix ("10.201.0.5", "10.201.2.4") -DestinationPortRange (514, 6514) | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup`

Answer (score 2):

You should provide an array as an input, not a string with commas:

```
-DestinationPortRange (1128, 1129, 4239)
```

or use `"1128", "1129", "4239"` if it doesnt cast them to strings automatically. `DestinationPortRange` accepts an array.

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/add-aznetworksecurityruleconfig?view=azps-2.2.0#parameters

Comment: hi, how this can be made into a ps array, eg, i need to pass them in $range which contains "1128","1129","4239" thank you

Comment: not sure i follow. `(1128,1129,4239)` is a ps array

Comment: my apologies, this is how i wanted , instead of -DestinationPortRange (1128, 1129, 4239), -DestinationPortRange $values

Comment: sure: `$values = 1,2,3; $nsg | Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -DestinationPortRange $values`

Comment: just tried, i think there is a catch, declaring it as $values = 1,2,3; didn't help but declaring it as [array]$values = 1,2,3; did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: well that makes no sense: `$val1 = 1,2,3; [array]$val2 = 1,2,3; Compare-Object $val1 $val2`